# file_regex captured group names

Tags: c#, sublimetext2, solution, build-system

I am trying to use Sublime Text 2 as a IDE for C#. I installed the [MSBuild](https://github.com/tillig/SublimeMSBuild) package, modified it a little so it starts the `msbuild` with solution file as parameter:

```
"cmd": ["msbuild", "$project_base_name.sln"],
```

The problem I have is how to specify the `file_regex` - the error messages display file name relative to project file:

```
Modules\HomeModule.cs(19,34): error CS1026: ) expected 
  [C:\Projects\MySolution\Project1\Project1.csproj]
```

and the `file_regex`

```
"file_regex": "^\\(s*).+?\\(([0-9]+),?([0-9]+)?\\):\\s*error(.*) \\[",
```

captures `Modules\HomeModule.cs`, line 19, column 34, and after clicking this error a non-existing file `Modules\HomeModule.cs` relative to the working folder (the solution folder) is opened (`C:\Projects\MySolution\Modules\HomeModule.cs`)

My question is if Sublime Text is only using positional regular express groups (i.e. 1st captured group value is file name, 2nd line, ...) or can I use named groups and backreferences to correctly capture the corrent file name (`C:\Projects\MySolution\Project1\Modules\HomeModule.cs`)?